# IntSummaryStatistics returns a result with a comma seperator while that's not the case for all other doubles or floats

Tags: java, java-8, summary

In the following code that I took from [a tutorial](https://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/) I get a weird result.

```
IntSummaryStatistics ageSummary =
    persons
      .stream()
      .collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(p -> p.age));

System.out.println(ageSummary);
// IntSummaryStatistics{count=4, sum=76, min=12, average=19,000000, max=23}
```

The average is a comma separated double, this is the first time ever that I get a comma separated double in Java. In all other cases I get a period separated double. For instance:

```
System.out.println(1.0); // 1.0
```

I checked my locale and it's set at en_US, I even tried to set it manually with the following arguments:

```
-Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en
```

Didn't change anything.
What could be the reason? The fact that I live in Belgium shouldn't influence the JVM I guess, or would it? Thanks.

Edit:

Below I've added the toString() and getAverage() method of the class. And it's already been clarified that it's a class within the JDK.

```
    public String toString() {
    return String.format(
        "%s{count=%d, sum=%d, min=%d, average=%f, max=%d}",
        this.getClass().getSimpleName(),
        getCount(),
        getSum(),
        getMin(),
        getAverage(),
        getMax());
}

public final double getAverage() {
    return getCount() > 0 ? (double) getSum() / getCount() : 0.0d;
}
```

[Link to the javadoc.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html#toString--)

And now I realized that if I print with `String.format("%f", 1.0)` I also get the comma separator. Never really saw that earlier, I probably looked over it before.

Edit 2:
jdk1.8.0_181 is my JDK version.

Comment: what is the type of 'average' ? also: what is in the toString method of IntSummaryStatistics?

Comment: @Stultuske that's a JDK class

Comment: strange, could you update the question with the exact JDK version and your Person class as well?

Comment: @nullpointer wanted to second that :)

Comment: @nullpointer yes, thank you for the clarification. still doesn't say anything about what is coded in the toString method.

Comment: @Stultuske Made some edits for clarification. I forgot to mention that my JDK is 1.8

Comment: no no, we need the *exact* version

Comment: @Eugene 1.8.0_181 is the exact version.

Comment: Looks very much like a system locale issue to me. :/

Comment: what happens if you print `System.out.println(String.format("%f", 1.0D / 0.2D));
` just that?

Comment: @Eugene 5,000000 is the result.

Comment: you got your answer now ;) it's a locale thingy

Comment: @Eugene System.out.println(Locale.getDefault()); gives me en_US though, it seems like it doesn't pay attention to that Locale then I guess.

Comment: or under that locale the format in changed, I *think* you can do that; have not played with that in a while, what OS are you on?

Comment: @Eugene I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise SP1

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! I guess there isn't much that I can do to change the string format locale within the toString method of IntSummaryStatistics. Or the string.format method itself, I find it weird that it uses the Locale of my system instead of the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

```
System.out.println(5.0);         // 1
System.out.printf("%f%n", 5.0);  // 2
```

Line 1 goes through `PrintStream`, which is specified to perform the conversion using `Double.valueOf`, which in turn is specified to use [`Double.toString(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)). That converts the double value into a string using a fixed format, which is not locale-specific.

By contrast, line 2 uses [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) which performs a locale-specific conversion. Clearly, there's something in your locale that specifies a comma as the decimal separator.

Note that the locale is richer than just "en_US" (language and country). The JDK can pick up information from the desktop environment. On Mac and Windows, at least, a bunch of individual formatting customizations can be applied. (I didn't think the JDK picked these up until later releases, but some might have made it into 8u181.) Also check the value of `Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT))`. The fact that you're in Belgium and not the U.S. is significant. Perhaps you made a setting in your system's internationalization control panel in order to get some numeric formatting to work properly.

Comment: Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT)) (I didn't know I had to put in an argument before) returns nl_BE. So it seems to be set at where I live where we use the comma, I see that I can change this with the system settings so that I can set it at en_US. Like that I get the desired period separator. I wish I could override that within the application though without the necessity of explicitly using the locale as an argument within formatters.

Comment: @alimranbay Calling `Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);` should set the main locale as well as the DISPLAY and FORMAT locale categories all to the US locale.

Comment: Well yeah that solved the problem. I can't believed I looked over that the whole time. Thanks a lot!